# Couldn't Access Amazon EC2 instance from Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, android-emulator

I have hosted a web service in AWS EC2, and can access the URL from web Browser using the Public DNS. When I access it by running it from android Emulator, Its throwing "java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host Instance.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/getJSON"

i)I have given permission for INTERNET in Android Manifest. 
ii)I have a open gateway permission 0.0.0.0:0 in security group of EC2
Where am I going wrong?

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your json file resides
            // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
            url = new URL("http://Instance.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/getJSON");




        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");


            // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Printing stack "+e1.toString());
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");


}
```

Comment: Your URL doesn't  seem to be accessible. It seems a get URL but still I am unable to access it correctly. See if your webservices are hosted correctly and you have done current firewall setup

Comment: copy and paste the real url from your code to your browser and make sure it is accessible. Most likely you have a mistype there.

Comment: Thanks for the Answers. @kapsym, the URL I have mentioned here is not the real one.I have modified it for security reasons. But I can get the proper response when I access it from Web Browser.

Comment: @Putnik Is it safe to paste the URL here? I don't know about the security vulnerabilities of AWS. I'm new to it

Comment: I mean not here, just for you to test.

Comment: Yes. It is Accessible. Is it the right way? or there is any specific Client code to access AWS servers?

Comment: There is no special code needed to access a website running on an EC2 instance. Have you tried loading other websites in your Android emulator to make sure it has the ability to access the internet? Also, the error sounds like a DNS resolution issue. You might try using the public IP of the EC2 instance instead of the host name.

Comment: A better practice would be to put it behind a DNS record, so you won't have to update the client if that instance dies, all you will have to do is update the DNS record.  Is the Instance on a public subnet? Is port 80 open on the security group? Can you curl from your desktop and get the JSON file?

Comment: Thanks for the Answers. @Mark Yes I tried loading the page from Emulator's browser it retrieved the data successfully.But not when I run the  application.I tried using the public IP too but the result is same :(

Comment: Thanks @strongjz .Put it behind the DNS record? Sorry I couldn't understand, Please share a tutorial link if possible. Yes the security group setting is Open 0.0.0.0/0 . How to check if instance is in Public subnet.I can curl successfully from by Local Yes. I'm new to AWS sorry for so much queries

Comment: To answer the DNS piece here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html

Comment: The instance should have a public IP and the subnet should have a route to an Internet Gateway.

Comment: @strongjz Thanks again. Now I have configured Elastic IP and got a permanent DNS. The Instance has a public IP . How to check if the Subnet has route to internet Gateway?

Comment: I can access and  get Json from the Pubic IP, even by using Browser in Emulator but couldn't access it only via running my App.

Comment: I would say that your infrastructure is fine then since you can get it from the browser and the emulator. Can you see the errors from app on the phone? I would add some more debugging and logging output. .

Comment: Thank you so much for you replies. I fixed it by changing the http Client I used Instead of "httpUrlConnectin" I used "AsyncHttpClient" and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Client I was using couldn't handle the response from the URL which I used,I used AsynHttpClient to fix this.Source link: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/